# Tomcat SSO Kerberos Realm

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, keytab

I managed to enable SSO in my web application using keytab.
I had to update following files to make it work:

Jass.conf

Krb5.conf

Server.xml  (Realm)

web.xml

Its working fine.My question is why I need to use Realm to search user again with Active Directory when user has already been authenticated using keytab?

Our application is open to all people in organization so I just want to get user principal from keytab and don't want to use Realm.

If I remove the Realm section from server xml, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The Realm is a user database. The realm enable the  and .
If you declare security constraint wihtout Realm you will end up with a 401 error. It might be your case.

I always had used a Realm but I think that if you remove all your security constraint it might work.